# Endpoint to access sbt releases

Tags: sbt

We have a policy against caching the releases directly from GitHub for security reasons. We were relying on https://sbt-downloads.cdnedge.bluemix.net/releases to access various sbt releases and cache them internally. Unfortunately, this endpoint is no longer reachable. Is there an alternate endpoint or archive to https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/ ? Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for calling out! In that case, please recommend how and where this question should be phrased and posted. Thanks!

Comment: There isn't one, AFAIK. None of the [se] sites accept requests for external links, because links have a tendency to die or move, and no one maintains them to keep them updated.